# Unable to set xAxis min for Highstock (Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart very similar to this fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/yse0Lkq2/

And I am trying to set a xAxis.min even if the `min` has no value (I'm hoping it could show blank white space rather than nothing at all). I tried setting:

```
    xAxis: {
        min: 1147284425000, 
        minRange: 30 * 1000,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    }
```

Hoping that both the chart and the navigator could start with "1147284425000", which equals `(GMT): Wed, 10 May 2006 18:07:05 GMT` , but I'm not seeing any differences here.

What am I missing here?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things to mention:

- `rangeSelector.selected` option prevents min, remove that one
- `xAxis.min` is not enough, add also `xAxis.max` to see the change
- it won't work until you will set `xAxis.ordinal` to false. Ordinal option displays points **equally** on the available space, so there is no place for "empty space"

And working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yse0Lkq2/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I am getting your questions completely or not but from what I got is you are trying to set the minimum for navigator. 
Please try setextreme function.
Ref : http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes

Hope that helps
Manish